# What is meant by the "speed of rotation" here?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, differential-geometry, surfaces

To make a long story short: I have a surface $X: I \to \mathbb{R}^3$ that sends $(u ,v) \in I \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ to $X(u,v) \in \mathbb{R}^3$. Consider these two family of surfaces:

$\hat{X}(u,v,t) = \sqrt{2bt + 1}\exp\left( \frac{\log(2bt + 1)}{2b} A\right) X(u,v)$

$F(u,v,t) = \sqrt{2bt + 1}\exp\left( t A\right) X(u,v)$

where $b \in \mathbb{R}$ is a constant and $A$ is an orthogonal matrix with determinant $1$. In the [thesis I'm reading](https://dspace.mit.edu/handle/1721.1/83693)
 (page 45, the dilation and rotation section) the author writes (not exactly as I put it here, but I just made things simpler so I could understand, there's no loss of generality) that, under $\hat{X}$, $X$ rotates with decreasing speed if $b > 0$ and with increasing speed if $b < 0$, and that under $F$, $X$ rotates with constant speed. This is supposed to be obvious but I'm not quite seeing it and I'd appreciate some help.

*EDIT*: Turns out it was just a matter of analysing the signs of $\dfrac{\partial \hat{X}}{\partial t}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find where it says that $A$ orthogonal matrix with determinant 1 is a rotation.

As food for thought, if $Q(t)$ are rotations, which are of the form

$$Q(t)=\exp(t\cdot  S)$$

for skew symmetric matrices (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axis%E2%80%93angle_representation#Relationship_to_other_representations) and the links there) then $Q'(t)=Q(t)\,S$ and so

$$Q^T(t)\,Q'(t)=Q^{-1}(t)\,Q(t)\,S=S.$$

So

$$\exp(h(t)\cdot Q^T(t)\,Q'(t))$$

is really again just a rotation and $\phi=h(t)$ is a parametrization of angles. Not sure if those bullet points all apply here, but if they do, then you got your explanation.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more? I'm still not sure what the author means by "speed' here.

Comment: Take the matrix $I:=\{\{0,1\},\{-1,0\}\}$ and compute $T(t):=\exp(t\cdot I)$. You will find that this is the rotation matrix. Consider the vector $x_0:=\{1,0\}$ and consider the vector $x(t):=T(t)\cdot x_0$. This is the unit vector which rotates around zero. You should get familiar with a solver or language where you can draw and animate such things, possibly create gifs - that helps to understand this. Now the matrix $S(t):=\exp(t^7\cdot I)$ will give another rotation matrix, but as opposed to $T(t)$, the action $S(t)\cdot x_0$ doesn't make for a steady rotation, but an accelerating one.

Comment: Thanks. I think I understand what you mean now. I'm still gonna leave the question open because I haven't yet figured out how (in the case I mentioned) the speed of the rotation is increasing if $b < 0$ and decreasing if $b > 0$.